# Warining related to array.prototype.map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, key, array.prototype.map

I was working and I encountred the warning each chiled should have ... (I have .map)
So I added a key on the 1st div after the map (like it should be), but for the 1st time I encounter this new warning "Encountered two children with the same key"

this is the code

```js
  const renderCondidate = () => {
    if (addCandidate.length) {
      return addCandidate.map((elem, index) => {
        return (
          <CFooter style={{ display: "flex" }} key={{ index }}>
            <CForm className="form-horizontal" style={{ width: "100%" }}>
              <CFormGroup
                style={{ width: "100%" }}
                row
                className="condidateContainrer"
              >
                <CCol md="3 mt-2">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="btn btn-success"
                    onClick={() => {
                      deleteCondidate(elem);
                    }}
                  >
                    {elem}
                  </button>
                </CCol>
                <CCol md="8 mt-2">
                  <CCallout color="danger">
                    {" "}
                    More Informations will appear here fefef ef
                    effefvgegezgezgnjz
                  </CCallout>
                </CCol>
              </CFormGroup>
            </CForm>
          </CFooter>
        );
      });
    }
  };
```

thank you!

Comment: You're passing an object as the key, not the index. Change `key={{ index }}` to `key={index}`. Then please read in detail on [keys in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) and why using the index can be dangerous.

Comment: oh yea, that was stupid, Thank you :))))))

Comment: @BrianThompson Has it. Voting to close as "unreproducible or caused by type". Cheers.

Comment: @DrewReese how to vote?

Comment: It's the "Close" link at the bottom of your post. I don't think you can vote on your own posts though. There are currently 2 close votes.